# Three different lists into one list

Tags: python, list

I have three lists

```
a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
b = ['123', '456', '789']
c = ['mar23', 'feb223', 'jan12']
```

How can I make this as follows:

```
d = ['abc 123 mar23', 'def 456 feb223', 'ghi 789 jan12']
```

presently I am doing a for loop and doing index based concatenation. There should be an elegant way. Especially the space between them is causing the challenge. 
I am not looking for a dictionary.

Comment: Could you show the actual code you use? When you say "faster", do you have millions of items in the real data, or do you just want something more *elegant*?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and list comprehension:

```
[' '.join(z) for z in zip(a, b, c)]
```

Result:

```
['abc 123 mar23', 'def 456 feb223', 'ghi 789 jan12']
```

Using index based vs `zip` runtime (`n=1000000`):

```
with index: 5.751067761
with zip:   4.115390091
```

Comment: `zip` is not faster than a for loop.

Comment: I have made a thorough evaluation. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Python's [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
In [1]: a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'] 
   ...: b = ['123', '456', '789'] 
   ...: c = ['mar23', 'feb223', 'jan12']                                                                      
In [2]: [' '.join(t) for t in zip(a, b, c)]                                                                   
Out[2]: ['abc 123 mar23', 'def 456 feb223', 'ghi 789 jan12']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Zip() function simply like this:

```
a = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
b = ['123', '456', '789']
c = ['mar23', 'feb223', 'jan12']

d = zip(a, b, c)

print(tuple(d))
```

Let me explain what is happening: We are first declaring 3 variables. Then, in order to join them together, we have a function zip() in Python which zips(or combines) the lists.
So once we zip(a, b, c), we simply combine these 3 variables as a tuple while printing d(which contains the zipped items).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
d = [f'{a[i]} {b[i]} {c[i]}' for i,x in enumerate(a)]
```

Output:

```
['abc 123 mar23', 'def 456 feb223', 'ghi 789 jan12']
```

As in the accepted answer it is claimed that `zip` is faster than `loop`, I have made an extensive evaluation of both of them. The results show that if for smaller lists `loop` performs faster, but as the number of the elements increase `zip` outperforms. Here some graphs:

**1. Amount of indices in the interval `[4,64]`:**
[image]

**2. Amount of indices in the interval `[64,4194304]`:**
[image]

Comment: While this works, OP is already doing index based concatenation.

Comment: @r.ook based on the question, it is not clear that he is using list comprehension or not. Additionally, `zip` is not faster than list comprehension and he is asking for more faster performance

Comment: `zip` is definitely a faster implementation.  Perhaps you should test it out.

Comment: @r.ook this is not correct. See the update of my answer.

Comment: Are you testing against the `list(...)` or list comprehension of `zip`? My updated answer uses a list comprehension of `zip`.  My test result was ran against OP's with your suggestion, which is a small set of `list`s, and it's still faster.  AFAIK `zip` runs with C behind the scene so it's almost certainly faster than native python.

Comment: @r.ook I tested your code in your answer against mine. Regarding your statement that `zip` runs with C behind it, please refer the source. As far as I know, this is not true and this is also the reason of using numpy functions. Numpy is based on C which makes it faster than normal python list functions.

Comment: I mean, the source code is right there: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c.  Python is written in C, and so are its built-ins.  Relying on the built-in functions will almost always get you better performance out of native python code like for loops, much like you observed in your graph.